# Faster way to iterate in numpy / pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, iteration

I have a big portfolio of bonds and I want to create a table with days as index, the bonds as columns and the notional of the bonds as values.

I need to put at 0 the rows before the starting date and after the terminating date of each bond.

Is there a more efficient way than this:

```
[[np.where( (day>=bonds.inception[i]) & 
(day + relativedelta(months=+m) >= bonds.maturity[i] ) & 
(day <= bonds.maturity[i]), 

bonds.principal[i],

0)   

for i in range(bonds.shape[0])] for day in idx_d]
```

### input example:

| id | nom | inception | maturity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38 | 200 | 22/04/2022 | 22/04/2032 |
| 87 | 100 | 22/04/2022 | 22/04/2052 |

### output example:

| day | 38 | 87 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21/04/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 22/04/2022 | 100 | 200 |

Comment: Do you have an example input and example output dataframe? Just a short one, 5 lines could probably do it. Leave out any unnecessary columns. Using that as a starting point may be easier than to read and understand your code.

Comment: Are the days a datetime or just an integer?

Comment: I'm trying to add these 2 tables but it always says "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Comment: days are datetime

Comment: For code, you can also use three backticks, ```, just before the first line, and just after the last line. That is often easier.

Comment: With the toolbar: select the code/tables, then click the icon that is two braces: `{}`.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: ok i think i did it

Comment: So each column in the output table corresponds to an index value in the input table?

Comment: And what range of dates do you want to span? I see a 2032 year, creating an index of days between now and that year is some 3600 days (and thus rows) in the output dataframe.

Comment: yes exactly each ID is a bond

Comment: the range is like 40 years, daily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below still requires a loop. I don't know if it's faster, or whether you find it clear, but I'll offer it as an alternative.

Create an example dataframe (with a few extra bonds for demonstration purposes):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [38, 87, 49, 51, 89], 
                   'nom': [200, 100, 150, 50, 250],
                   'start_date': ['22/04/2022', '22/04/2022', '01/01/2022', '01/05/2022', '23/04/2012'],
                   'end_date': ['22/04/2032', '22/04/2052', '01/01/2042', '01/05/2042', '23/04/2022']})
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])
df = df.set_index('id')
print(df)
```

This then looks like:

| id | nom | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38 | 200 | 2022-04-22 00:00:00 | 2032-04-22 00:00:00 |
| 87 | 100 | 2022-04-22 00:00:00 | 2052-04-22 00:00:00 |
| 49 | 150 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2042-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 51 | 50 | 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | 2042-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 89 | 250 | 2012-04-23 00:00:00 | 2022-04-23 00:00:00 |

Now, create a new blank dataframe, with 0 as the default value:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(data=0, columns=df.index, index=pd.date_range('2022-04-20', '2062-04-22'))
new.index.rename('day', inplace=True)
```

Then, iterate over the columns (or index of the original dataframe), selecting the relevant interval and set the column value to the relevant 'nom' for that selected interval:

```
for column in new.columns:
    sel = (new.index >= df.loc[column, 'start_date']) & (new.index <= df.loc[column, 'end_date'])
    new.loc[sel, column] = df.loc[df.index == column, 'nom'].values
print(new)
```

which results in:

| day | 38 | 87 | 49 | 51 | 89 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-20 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 150 | 50 | 250 |
| 2022-04-21 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 150 | 50 | 250 |
| 2022-04-22 00:00:00 | 200 | 100 | 150 | 50 | 250 |
| 2022-04-23 00:00:00 | 200 | 100 | 150 | 50 | 250 |
| 2022-04-24 00:00:00 | 200 | 100 | 150 | 50 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2062-04-21 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2062-04-22 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

[14613 rows x 5 columns]

Comment: I tested it. It is a bit faster, I'd say not the ultimate speed, probably it is possible to do it in a faster way, but it's already better. Thanks